# Verbal Job Offer Confirmation but actual letter still pending

Tags: professionalism, job-offer

I have cleared all three interviews for this job and a successful reference check has also been done.

A week after reference check, I called the HR to check the status of the whole hiring process. He told me that they are pleased to offer me this job and the actual offer letter will follow in couple of days.

Its been 2 weeks after my last call to the HR and still no offer letter. I emailed him and he replied "We don't have a start date yet, I'll send you an offer letter as soon as I am able to."

Is this usual in the HR world?

Comment: Check your spam folder. This happened to me--the HR people said it was still coming but the letter was in my spam box for a week before I realized.

Comment: I think your question at the end should be more like "How should I proceed". Whether it is normal or not you have to go forward with whatever you'd like to do. I would suggest not waiting around for them, obviously continue looking for a solid offer and I would prefer a solid offer with a start date and signed letter over an offer where they can't even tell you the start date yet. What if the start date is in 6 months?? It's already two weeks so maybe you could put some pressure on them tactfully like "I really am looking forward to working here but if I don't know the start date..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congrats on getting the offer.

Having said that, take the HR person at their word that they don't have a start date - you've got no reason to doubt them - and plan on following up up regularly, say once a week, asking if they have a start date lined up.

And keep reiterating in your follow ups that the reason that you are following up is that you had a good experience interviewing with them, that they made you feel that you will be comfortable working with them and that you look forward to working with them, and (if you want to be super courteous) that you apologize in advance for any inconvenience you may be causing them by having them respond to your follow ups.